# Error: Statbin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat= “count”?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

So I’m currently trying to create a histogram and I get the message above. Not sure what’s going wrong or anything. The code I’m currently using is:

```
 G1 = ggplot(world_data, aes(x= gdp_10_thou)) + 
   geom_histogram() + 
   theme(axis.text.x= element_text(size= 12)) +
     xlab(“…”) + ylab(“…”) 

 ggplot(world_data, aes(x= gdp_10_thou)) + 
    geom_histogram() + 
    theme(axis.text.x= element_text(size= 12)) + 
    xlab(“…”) + ylab(“…”)
```

I then get the error: statBin etc message.

Can someone help with this please[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcWGV.jpg)
I’ve added in the scale_x_continuous() previously and then it would say “error: discrete value supplied to continuous scale”

Comment: Welcome to SO. I guess the error message is fairly clear in this case. Your x variable is discrete, but it needs to be continuous. check `str(world_data$gdp_10_thou)` and it will tell you if it is character or factor, and convert it to numeric with `world_data$gdp_10_thou <- as.numeric(world_data$gdp_10_thou)`.

Comment: Yes! It worked thank you!! I’m not sure why this happened but thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Kristy, for future reference, this is a case where searching for the error message would have gotten you the answer. You say you are not sure why this happened ... try doing class(world_data$gdp_10_thou) and you will see that the result is not numeric. This probably happened when you read in the data and you could fix it there if you want.